# Cores dos botões criados no Ionic Creator não ficam no projeto como no mockup

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Criei um layout utilizando o Ionic Creator, exportei mas as cores de botões e outros elementos criados (na versão 3 do Ionic) estão TODOS azuis.

Segue um código exemplo:

```
<div id="wellFit-button-bar1" class="button-bar">            
                <a href-inappbrowser="page2" id="wellFit-button12" class="ion-button button-stable button-block icon ion-android-person"></a>
                <a ui-sref="menu.workoutDoDia()" id="wellFit-button13" class="button button-stable button-block icon ion-android-contract"></a>
                <a ui-sref="menu.ranks()" id="wellFit-button9" class="button button-stable button-block icon ion-fireball"></a>
                <a ui-sref="menu.movimentos()" id="wellFit-button14" class="button button-stable button-block icon ion-lock-combination"></a>
                <a ui-sref="menu.mais()" id="wellFit-button16" class="button button-stable button-block icon ion-android-menu"></a>            
        </div>
```

Observe que os botões no código estão stable mas eles ficam TODOS em azul.

Como corrigir isso?

Comment: ele exporta algum css?

Comment: Exporta apenas a pasta SRC com os arquivos de layout, mas os CSS vêm em branco, tanto das telas quanto o app.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Creator do Ionic para a versão 3 ainda está em fase de testes e pega muito do Ionic 1 e um pouco do 3. É preciso pegar a documentação e ir corrigindo o código.